# Attacking grouping sets of values functionally

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given a map associating indices to values, how do I create a separate map that accumulates the values that are *above* a particular threshold when the number of values that can be grouped together cannot exceed some limiting value?

For example, given a mapping like this:

`val raw = Map(0 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 2)`

Group those values **over** 2 together but each grouping can only contain at most the sum of 2 values such that if the first value is >= 2 then the grouping would contain a single value. In contrast, if the 1st value is less than 2, the grouping will be of size 2 with a value consisting of the same of the 1st value and the second value.

Executing that on the mapping above would yield a map of the group's index to the value, e.g.,

`Map(0 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2) // Result`

Obviously the way to do this in a non-functional way would be like this:

```scala
var c = 0
var sortedIndex = 0
var acc: Map[Int, Int] = Map() // Result accumulator
val limit = 2 // Anything larger will be forced into the next group

while (c < raw.size) {
  if (raw(c) >= limit) {
    acc = acc ++ Map(sortedIndex -> raw(c))
    c = c + 1      
  } else {
    acc = acc ++ Map(sortedIndex -> raw(c) + raw(c + i)
    c = c + 2        
  }
  sortedIndex = sortedIndex  + 1
}

acc
```

How would I do this functionally? I.e., immutable states, reducing my use of loops. (I understand that loops are not "dead" in FP, just trying to reinforce a use case where I can get away with NOT using loops.)

Comment: Your code, as posted, doesn't make much sense and can't produce the desired result: `i` is never defined or initialized, and `sortedIndex` is never modified.

Comment: @jwvh fixed. Forgot to change the names from my scratchpaper.

Comment: Why are you using a `Map` as an indexed sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need to work with Map for this problem. Since the key of the map is simple index. Any case the following work for your problem:

```
  val testLimit = 2 // Update the constants as required
  val takeUpto = 2

  def accumulator(input: List[Int], output: List[Int] = List.empty[Int]): List[Int] = {
    input match {
      case Nil                               => output // We have reached at the end of the input
      case head :: tail if head >= testLimit => accumulator(tail, output :+ head)
      case m =>
        val (toSum, next) = m.splitAt(takeUpto)
        accumulator(next, output :+ toSum.sum)
    }
  }

  // Map(0 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 2) // Result
  // val raw = Map(0 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 2) equivalent is List(2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)
  println(accumulator(List(2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)))
```